# Regex that matches a string that does not contain a specific string

Tags: regex

From time to time I come across this problem and I finally want a solution for this once and for all.

It's best to come up with an example that could be used practically. Imagine you have an application with a lot of INSERT-INTO-statements using mysql and php and you want to find statements that do not have a mysql_real_escape_string() because they would be vulnerable for sql injection. To keep it simple, let's assume that each query ends with a semicolon.

**So how do you match strings that start with "INSERT INTO" and end with ";" and don't contain "mysql_real_escape_string"?**

My assumption is that the quantifiers you have to use (+ and *) and the fact that a regex always is trying to match will lead to the behaviour that the regex eats just as much characters that a lookahead or lookbehind for the not contained string does not find it, even it is there. That's the core problem, I think.

Comment: I know this is not an answer, but the mysql_XXX API is basically broken. Better use mysqli_XXX or PDO; these allow for prepared statements, which is the actual answer to SQL injection. 'mysql_' is easy to grep for, BTW.

Comment: Not only `insert` queries can be vulnerable, just wanted to note.

Comment: It was just an example. I am not interested in escaping and don't even use mysql. Maybe I should change it to something totally random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use negative lookahead:

```
^INSERT INTO(?!mysql_real_escape_string)(.(?!mysql_real_escape_string))*;$
```

Comment: Tried it with "INSERT INTO sdfsdffsfd mysql_real_escape_string sdfsdf;" which didn't work. As expected, ".*" eats up almost everything and after that "mysql_real_escape_string" can't be found. This happens even with an ungreedy quantifier. Because the regex tries to match.

Comment: That's great! Now I remember, I even used something like that a long time ago. It's quite an important pattern. Every single character is read and then it is checked if the string does not appear after it. Thanks!